# Stripes ActionBean get client PUT data

Tags: ios, put, stripes, mdm

I'm trying to implement a iOS MDM server in Java with stripes.

I want the iDevice to checkin to a ActionBean, but how do I get the data from the iDevice's PUT request?

The data that the iDevice will send is the one below.

```
PUT: /checkin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>MessageType</key>
    <string>Authenticate</string>
    <key>Topic</key>
    <string>com.example.mdm.pushcert</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string> [ redacted ] </string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a Servlet (extends HttpServlet) and overriding the doPut() method.

The servlet needs to be mapped in the web.xml file. (Running via jetty).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MDM</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.web.MDMServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MDM</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mdm-servlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```